# Typescript generic that extends the `keyof` a dictionary with keys constrained to `string` is not constrained to `string`

Tags: typescript, generics

If I have a dictionary `D` with the keys constrained to type `string`, generics that are of type `keyof D` seem to still be inferred as `string | number | symbol`.

A basic ts playground example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClA2gawhAC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwF1SBDWkLAXyywGM5aFKACMWlZFAAUwgDYsAFqQo0GASmQA+NFhyUIwAK6VaIufIDcXHpn6DgUAGYIJAHgAqUCAA9gEWgBMyWAQAGigAOU8fP0CoQhA4Byg3DUl-al5gUjcw+NJw9SQtDGwRMUl41UtS2zI4GQgAOhk4ejSM4CquIA).

```js
type Foo = {
  [key: string]: any
}

const bar = (blah: string) => {
  return blah;
}

const foo = <T extends Foo, N extends keyof T>(dict: T, key: N) => {
  bar(key); // Err: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  console.log(dict);
}
```

In the example above, how can I constrain `N` so that it:

- can be passed into `bar` and
- must be one of the keys of the dictionary `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
const sym = Symbol('mysym')
const test = { abc: 123, [sym]: 456 }
const foo: Foo = test // fine
```

So the type:

```
{ abc: number, [sym]: number }
```

Actually extends the type:

```
{ [key: string]: any }
```

---

If you want `N` to constrained to only strings, then you can just intersect that requirement with the constraint for `N`.

```
const foo = <
  T extends Foo,
  N extends keyof T & string
>(dict: T, key: N) => {
  return bar(key);
}

foo({ a: 123 }, 'a') // fine
foo({ a: 123 }, 'b') // error
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClA2gawhAC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwF1SBDWkLAXyywGM5aFKACMWlZFAAUwgDYsAFqQo0GASmQA+NN0x8BQgGYIJAHiw4AKlAgAPYBFoATMrAQAac1ABy1uw+dQhCBwBlBWAGTkVHT0WBqSjtS8wKQWboFEpF7qSFoY2FCUEMAArpS0ImKSQaoA3Fw8mEZwkqhQLKQAjABMAMxQnOkA5CxD6gD041AGdBBYza3tXX0Dw8JjUJPWlJRwlEA)